# Like, Tray icon and Dock Icon is there anything like desktop icon in MAC OS X?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I've created an application and want its icon to be displayed on my desktop mind it i don't want a shortcut. It should be an icon as it is on tray and dock, like when i click it application should launch. AND ALL THIS I WANT IT **PROGRAMMATICALLY.**

Plz help i'm a newbie,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since the application in OS X is just a folder with '.app' extension , general practice would be to allow user place it where ever he wants. But you can do a symbolic link on desktop via UNIX API or just calling `ln` util like this `ln -s my.app ~/Desktop/my.app` (and yes, that would be a shortcut)

Comment: This is a crappy question. A. That's not how OS X does things. Apps should normally be in /Applications and you schools learn about launch pad  B. Dmitry explained the rest

Comment: @DmitryG. - i don't want a shortcut. ok! i'll adjust with a shortcut also i created a symbolic link. now i have to change its icon at runtime is that possible. Sir?

Comment: @uchuugaka: I accept that it should be in applications folder. But there can be exceptions, and like to try some more on the same page. what is the harm??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing as desktop icon,
instead create hardlink via `NSFileManager`'s function.

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] linkItemAtPath:&lt;application path>
                                                toPath:shortCutDestPath
                                                 error:&error];
```

This won't show that shortcut arrow also like it shows in soft link.

Comment: @uchuugaka : ok! method :-)

Comment: You're not supposed to create hard links to directories and app bundles are directories. It's not normally possible on most Unixes. OS X added it to support Time Machine, but its use for other purposes is discouraged. Also, it won't work across file systems, like if the user keeps /Applications and their home on separate volumes.